# .htaccess rewrite rule for specific URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

When user hit a URL like this

`www.mydomain.com/premium-pro/somepage.html`

It should map to the 
`www.mydomain.com/myfile.php`

and I should be able to access `somepage.html` as a `$_GET` parameter in `myfile.php`

I have `.htaccess` under `mydomain.com` but very new to rewrite rules and not sure what kind of rule should be written there. I did research on this but didn't get succeed.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below rule in root, I've taken a var variable for `$_GET` data.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/premium-pro/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ myfile.php?var=%1 [L]
```

Comment: I get 404 not found error. The request is not getting mapped with myfile.php

Comment: Try here it is working http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=66069988-004f-5155-80b7-08046a8b7edb

Comment: Hey, 404 gone but now it is 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Do you have some other rule? which might conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule myfile.php ./premium-pro/somepage.html
```

Comment: The somepage.html is a variable thing. it can be somthingelse.html. You made it static in .htaccess